# Need help identifying where coin transfer is and how to get it back

Tags: transactions, wallets, address.transfer, wallet-transfer, transfer

I Transferred some ENJ coins from my DeFI wallet to what I thought was my Trading account wallet. Long story short the address it I was sent too was off by one number. About 3/4 of the way into the address it’s a 3 and was supposed to be a 2. Everything else is exactly the same address wise. The ENJ is sitting in the address it was sent too but no body owns the address and I’m not sure if it’s a wallet or not. The address never existed besides when I transferred over to it. So literally it never ceased to exist until I sent. No prior history of transaction, no movement of the coins. No one owns it. I’ve tried to see if it’s an ETH wallet address and have gotten different answers from different sights. Please any information is helpful trying to be pointed in the right direction. Yes I’ve already contacted my wallet provider, the trading platform, ENJ support, and I’ve tried to get in contact with ETH support but have not heard from them in 2.5 weeks.

Comment: Unfortunately there is nothing you can do. In theory for each address there are many private keys. So unless you find the private key that generates that address the token are lost (the probability of doing that is zero).

Comment: What if the address never existed until I transferred the coins to it?

Comment: Addresses always existed. There's nothing that differentiate an address that had received funds from another that hasn't received any yet.